# How to allow non-existent privileges in Zend_Acl?

Tags: php, zend-framework, acl, privileges, blacklist

I'm using ZF 1.12.2, and I'd like to create a blacklist for my Zend_Acl privileges since I have less to restrict than to allow.  I'm basing my ACL resource names on my controller names and my privileges on my controller action names.

Right now, I deny privileges like this:

```
$acl->deny('user', null, 'User::login');
```

As I add actions to my User Controller, I'd like the user role to implicitly be granted access to them unless I explicitly deny them.  So, if I add an edit action on my User Controller, I don't have to do this:

```
$acl->allow('user', null, 'User::edit');
```

By default, `Zend_Acl::isAllowed` returns false if the privilege doesn't exist.  It is also difficult to know which privileges have been added unless I subclass and store them before I call the parent.  I've been trying to decipher `Zend_Acl::$_rules`, because I think it would suit my needs and I could avoid subclassing.  Is allowing non-existent privileges to pass `Zend_Acl::isAllowed` possible?

**UPDATE:**  Right now, my working subclass method `My_Acl::isAllowed` is below.  `My_Acl::__construct` accepts an array config consisting of roles with nested privileges/resources to add.

```
public function isAllowed($role = null, $resource = null, $privilege = null)
{
    if (null !== $resource) {
        if (is_string($resource)) {
            $resource_id = $resource;
        } else {
            $resource_id = $resource->getResourceId();
        }

        if (!in_array($resource_id, array_keys($this->_resources))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (null !== $privilege) {
        if (!in_array($privilege, array_keys($this->_privileges))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return parent::isAllowed($role, $resource, $privilege);
}
```

Comment: Can you add code to plugin where you are checking access. 'controller::action' this part basically.

Comment: @roko Added my overriding isAllowed method

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert with ACL but as I understand the usage you can `allow()` all and then `deny()` as required.

```
//user can do all, by not specifying resources or privileges, all is allowed
$acl->allow('user');

//explicitly deny specific resources and privileges
$acl->deny('user', null, 'User::login');
```

just be aware of any inheritance that is applied as that may cause unexpected behavior.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working.  Checking `$acl->isAllowed('user', null, 'bogusPrivilege')` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You have too many checks in your `isAllowed` method that makes things complicated

If you are not using modular approach (HMVC) you should use second parameter of `isAllowed(role, resource, privilege)` may be use controller as second parameter and action as third param like this: `$acl->allow('user', 'user', 'edit');`

If you follow this approach you will need to add the controller as a resource

```
//user controller as resource.
$this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('user'));
```

Define an arbitrary resource: `nullresources`

```
// any resource
$this->add(new Zend_Acl_Resource('nullresources'));       

$this->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest')); // guest role - no login (it's good to have something like this)

$this->allow('guest', 'nullresources');
```

If you add an arbitrary resource:  `nullresources` you can skip some steps in your isAllowed.

```
  /**
   *
   * @param string $role
   * @param string $resource (module name)
   * @param String $privilege (controller name: action name)
   * @return Boolean
   */
  public function isAllowed($role = null, $resource = null, $privilege = null)
  {
      /**
       *  by default, undefined resources are allowed to all
       */
      if (!$this->has($resource)) {
          $resource = 'nullresources';
      }
      return parent::isAllowed($role, $resource, $privilege);
  }
```

If you follow this approach you should be able to use it in this way:

```
$acl->allow('user', 'user');
$acl->deny('user', 'user', 'login');
```

**EDIT:**

You will also need to make changes to where ever you're doing the check i.e. bootstrap or some plugin may be if you're using plugin here's an example class

```
<?php 
class My_Acl_AccessCheck extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    private $_acl = null;

    public function __construct(Zend_Acl $acl)
    {
        $this->_acl = $acl;
    }

    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {            
        /**
         * get controller name
         * @var String $controller
         */
        $controller = $request->getControllerName();
        /**
         * get action name
         * @var String $action
         */
        $action = $request->getActionName();
        /**
         * getting the role from the registry and defining some
         * role for the null character as guest makes authentication more flexible
         * if the roles is not allowed to use the resource then the user is
         * redirected to action notAllowed of controller user
         *
         * Parameter passed for isAllowed: role, ControllerName, ActionName             
         */
        if(!$this->_acl->isAllowed(Zend_Registry::get('role'), $controller, $action))
        {
            $request->setModuleName('default')
                    ->setControllerName('user')
                    ->setActionName('notAllowed');
        }        

    }
}
```

In `bootstrap`

```
    $this->_acl = new My_Acl();
    $frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $frontController->registerPlugin(new My_Acl_AccessCheck($this->_acl));
```

Comment: I do like your initial allowance of null resources and resource checking in the overriding subclass method.  However, checking existence of privileges with Zend_Acl is another story.  Is it possible to tweak Zend_Acl to allow a blacklist approach to privileges and deny access to roles that way while allowing everything else?  I really would like to avoid repeating myself is the code exists in Zend_Acl.

Comment: I am a little confused with your approach. How are you mapping your roles to privileges and what does `$this->_privileges` hold? Blacklisted (denied) actions to the role?
If your mapping of roles to privileges is correct then your approach should have worked as well. 
Your approach would do similar thing as Zend_Acl does, I am still not sure why you wouldn't allow Zend_Acl to check for the stuff. And how does that make it repeating yourself?